# What is the difference between those kind of instantiation?

Tags: java, class, object, polymorphism, instantiation

it's maybe a newbie question but I think it will be helpful for some beginners.

My question is :

```
public abstract class Person {
    code goes here ....
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    code goes here ....
}
```

What is the difference between those kind of instantiation ?

```
Person student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);
```

and

```
Employee student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);
```

Comment: The type of the target variable is the only difference. Using the abstract type restricts you to using only the API defined by it.

Comment: let's say your Employee class provides a method that your Person class doesn't. Unless you cast your object to an Employee object, your first instantiation will not be able to use that method, since it's declared to be a Person, and is limited to the possibilities of Person

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially the same, but the compiler treats `Person student` as a `Person` without any type information from the concrete class `Employee`

Comment: but at the same time it treat Person student as an employee i'm a little confused !

Comment: @GhaithBriki You can cast it to `Employee` and it will work without a ClassCastException. You may want to read more about Polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same thing, but the difference is that:

1- In the first declaration:

```
Person student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);
```

Here `student` can't access `Employee` class specific `methods` or `attributes` as it's a `Person` object which contains an `Employee` instance.

2- But in the second one:

```
Employee student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);
```

Here `student` can benefit from both `Employee` and `Person` attributes and methods.

Please check **[Polymorphism Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)** for further reading about **polymorphism in `Java`**.

**Example:**

We can see that in this example, where we use `Integer` and `Object` classes:

```
Integer i1= new Integer(0);
//This will run and execute perfectly
System.out.println(i1.intValue());


Object i2= new Integer(0);      
//This will throw an error as `Object` class doesn't have `intValue()` method.
System.out.println(i2.intValue());
```

This is [a live **working Demo**](https://ideone.com/EWC1SR) so you can see that.

Answer (score -1):

Following is difference in both instantiation.

(1)
`Person student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);`

In this instantiation `student` is object of `Person` class so it can't access `Employee` class specific `methods` or `attributes`.

(2) 
`Employee student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);`

Here, in second instantiation `student` can access `Employee` class specific `methods` and `attributes` as well as `Person` class because it is extending in `Employee` class.

This is basic difference in this two statements.